# sp_stop_job reports Success, but the jobs are still running

Tags: sql-server, jobs

We have some jobs that run via the scheduler. We noticed today that some are still running from the weekend, and we need to kill them.

We have used `sp_stop_job` and it reports that the job has been stopped sucessfully, but looking at the Job Activity Monitor that status is still Executing: 1 (Subplan_1). I am using various queries to get the jobs that are currently running and the jobs still appear.

```
SELECT [sjv].[name], [sjv].[description], [sja].[run_requested_date], [sja].[last_executed_step_id]
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs_view] sjv
JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobactivity] sja
ON [sjv].[job_id] = [sja].[job_id]
WHERE [sja].[run_requested_date] is not null
AND [sja].[stop_execution_date] is NULL
```

How is this possible? Is it just sending an ABORT command or similar? And can I really kill the jobs immediately?

I'm rather new to this side of SQL.

Comment: Can you tell what, exactly, the job is still doing?  Is it waiting on something? What does sp_Whoisactive tell you?

Comment: Do any of these jobs make calls over a linked server or calls outside of SQL (e.g. such as a CmdExec or SSIS step)?

Comment: Yes over a linked server

Answer (score 3):

You should keep in mind that aborting a job does not always mean the job is aborted as expected. It could be that the transactions needed to be rolled back and this may also take a while depending on the amount of data and the performance.

Comment: And, just so that you know, sometimes SQL Agent jobs show that they are still running even though they failed hours or days earlier.